# No route to host centos

Tags: centos, iptables, firewall

I am trying to allow a port through a firewall on centos 6.

The error I am receiving is `telnet: connect to address 80.xx.xx.xx: No route to host`

The port I am trying to allow is 5666.

If I disable the firewall on the destination machine, I can connect, so I know it is a firewall issue.

I have added the rule with:

`iptables -N NRPE`

`iptables -I INPUT -s 0/0 -p tcp --dport 5666 -j NRPE`

then when I do `iptables -S` I see:

[paste bin link](http://pastebin.com/9VdLcmtw)

when I do `iptables -L`

[paste bin link 2](http://pastebin.com/Q9HwPPVV)

But I still cannot connect.

I can connect to many other machines on this port from the server I am using, it is only this destination machine that I cannot connect to when its firewall is enabled.

Help greatly appreciated. If I need to supply more info please let me know.

Comment: On the client side (the server you are telnetting from) post the results of `route -n`.  You could have a routing table issue.  If you stop iptables on the destination server, can you connect? Also note with NRPE you need to configuration authentication but that should not stop you from connecting to the port.

Comment: yes, If I disable the firewall on the destination machine I can connect

Comment: I'm not sure what your intention is with `-N NRPE` and `-j NRPE` but I'm confident it's not doing what you think it does.  Simply copy the ssh example `-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT` and change the port so the new statement would be `-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 5666 -j ACCEPT`.

Comment: Your `iptables -N` rule is creating a new chain.  Chains are processed and then passed back into the main rules.  So in this case your NRPE rule passes that traffic into the NRPE chain, which does not have an accept rule.  By default it will drop traffic.

Comment: @jeffatrackaid thanks, could you tell me how to remove the chain please?

Comment: Man pages are your friend.  http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables.man.html  see the delete chain rule.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your NRPE iptables chain does not appear to a have a default accept rule.

Unless you just want your own iptables chain for NRPE, you could use:

`iptables -I INPUT -s 0/0 -p tcp --dport 5666 -j ACCEPT`

This will add an accept rule to the default INPUT chain.

Otherwise, you need to add an accept rule to your NRPE chain.

`iptables -I NRPE -s 0/0 -p tcp --dport 5666 -j ACCEPT`

I don't see a need for an unique chain just for 1 port.  I recommend you clear your NRPE chain and just allow the `INPUT` rule above.

Comment: I used your first suggestion, that worked, thanks very much.